# Scilab - Is there a way to close Excel from the command line?

Tags: excel, scilab

Is there a way/function to close an Excel file from the command line ?

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the windows command line interface (cmd.exe), you can use

```
taskkill /F /IM excel.exe
```

which will forcibly close any processes called excel.exe that are currently running: the heavy-handed approach.

To close a workbook associated with a particular excel process is more difficult and not possible without using something like vbscript. Let me know if that's what you want to do.

Comment: sorry I meant the command line on scilab. Sorry for not being clear

Comment: I'll leave this answer up though, unless anyone objects. If you can 'shell out to DOS' using scilab then you could use the command I gave you.